# variable tablename and fieldname in Stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

When I try to save the following Stored procedure, I get the error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InventorySearch, Line 29
Incorrect syntax near '@FieldName'.

How can I pass in both `@TableName` and `@FieldName` and use them to define which table and field should be used to search the DB?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InventorySearch] 
    @FieldName AS nvarchar(50),
    @TableName AS nvarchar(50), 
    @SearchTerm nvarchar(50),
    @DeviceSearch bit
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT AssetTag.Value, Device.LK_User, Device.LK_Location, AssetTag.CreatedOn, Device.AssetTypeId, AssetTag.StatusTypeId, Device.DeviceID, Device.SerialNumber, Device.LogicallyDeleted

    FROM Device INNER JOIN AssetTag ON Device.DeviceID = AssetTag.DeviceID

   WHERE @TableName.@FieldName like @SearchTerm
END
```

Comment: You must use Dynamic SQL - EXEC/sp_executesql if object identifiers  are variables: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: This can be done using dynamic sql. and what I see in your question that you also need to join `@tablename` with your `device` and `assettag` tables so that you can use its column in where clause. please update your question with more info about how will you join `@tablename` with other two.

Comment: Be VERY careful if you use the dynamic sql approach as suggested by nearly everyone. Dynamic sql is extremely powerful but the methods offered so far are vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to Create [Dynamic SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as Below :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InventorySearch] 
    @FieldName AS nvarchar(50),
    @TableName AS nvarchar(50), 
    @SearchTerm nvarchar(50),
    @DeviceSearch bit
AS 
BEGIN
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)=

'SELECT AssetTag.Value, Device.LK_User, Device.LK_Location,
        AssetTag.CreatedOn, Device.AssetTypeId, AssetTag.StatusTypeId, 
        Device.DeviceID, Device.SerialNumber, Device.LogicallyDeleted
 FROM Device INNER JOIN AssetTag ON Device.DeviceID = AssetTag.DeviceID  
 WHERE '+ (@TableName)+ '.'+ 
          (@FieldName) 
        +' like ''%' + (@SearchTerm ) +'%'''

print (@SQL)
EXEC (@SQL)
END
```

Comment: Why are you casting TableName and FieldName to the same datatype they already are? You should wrap those variable in quotename at the very least to help prevent sql injection.

Comment: If you wrap those with quotename it would be much better since it would be less prone to sql injection. As posted, it is wide open.

Comment: One question ... @SearchTerm is the actual term that is being searched for. Why do I need to cast that?

Comment: @michaelk46 updated it before 5 min no casting is needed here

Answer (score 0):

you can write your code using dynamic query like below.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InventorySearch] 
    @FieldName AS nvarchar(50),
    @TableName AS nvarchar(50), 
    @SearchTerm nvarchar(50),
    @DeviceSearch bit
AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)=''
   SET @sql = 'SELECT AssetTag.Value, Device.LK_User, Device.LK_Location,  
        AssetTag.CreatedOn, Device.AssetTypeId, AssetTag.StatusTypeId, 
        Device.DeviceID, Device.SerialNumber, Device.LogicallyDeleted
  FROM Device INNER JOIN AssetTag ON Device.DeviceID = AssetTag.DeviceID
  WHERE '+@TableName+'.'+@FieldName+' like '+@SearchTerm+''

  EXEC (@sql)
END
```

Comment: you should use your @tableName in FROM clause.